# On a C# windows form application, do I need a manifest file if I'm not using ClickOnce?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce

If I deploy (Publish) a Windows Form application **without** the `ClickOnce` option, do I still need to deploy my application together with a `.manifest` file?

In other words, is the `.manifest` file needed for **none** `ClickOnce` installations?

Comment: You also need a manifest file if you want to require admin rights, for high DPI awareness, correct windows version detection, and (probably only for native not .NET) access to the latest Common Controls.  If you let Windows handle scaling and you don't have version-specific behavior then maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows before XP:**

Manifest is not required. The Windows version before XP will execute this exe file as before to find the corresponding dll. There is no separate Manifest, it is just a redundant file or resource, and the dll file will be directly searched in the system32 directory and called.

**Versions after WIN7:**

Manifest is required. Because the manifest generated by program packaging is the list of DLL resources you include, when the program is executed, it will first search for this file to find the corresponding DLL. When you port to another computer, the program searches for this file, but does not find the corresponding DLL (the DLL here contains the DLL used in your development environment, but it has no effect on the execution of the program), an error will be reported, so you delete it You will find that the program can be executed, but doing so will cause serious problems. It is recommended that you choose to generate all DLLs when compiling (use DLLs statically rather than shared).

Comment: Sorry, but this is quite confusing, IMHO.

Comment: @Christian.K Hello, in which aspects, maybe your point of view is more helpful to solve the OP's problem

Comment: Frankly, in every aspect (about DLLs lookup, etc.). Personally, I would have assumed that the comment that "Dave S" gave to the OPs question is what the issues/reasons could be to have a manifest outside of ClickOnce deployment.

Comment: @Christian.K Hello, I agree with some of Dave S's views. I only explain why winxp does not need .manifest from the aspect of dll search, but it is needed after win7. I also feel that the dll search is necessary to lead to this conclusion. I take your opinion. I will revisit this question